# MySql - An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using MYSQL database for that...I get this following Error...Please anyone can help me?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class formLogin
  Dim connStr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=ssknet;port=3306;password=;"
  Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=@username and password=@password", connection)


    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)

    If table.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success!")
    End If

    'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

I want to access database right now. Quick frnds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a critical step. You are not assigning any command to your adapter. It doesn't know how to query anything without a command

```
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Next, according to the [MySql Reserved KeyWords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), user and password are reserved and to use them in a query as field names you should put backticks (ALT+096) around them. So the query should be written as

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `user` 
                            WHERE username=@username 
                            AND `password`=@password", connection)
```

A part from this your code is good enough albeit there are a couple of thing to consider.

First, connection object should not be kept as global objects. This leads to many problems with the resources kept on the server and with closing/opening the connection when there is an error. Just create and discard the connection inside a using statement

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
Using connection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
   connection.Open()

   .... all of your code except the close connection

End Using ' this close the connection also in case of exceptions
```

Second, you don't need an SqlDataAdapter and a datatable if you just want to check if the user/password exists

```
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
if reader.HasRows then
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success!")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password")
End If
```

Third, it is a great security risk to keep password in plain text inside your database and then using queries to retrieve it. You should use [Salt and Hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) methods to store and retrieve password

Comment: It is already on. Look at the parameter passed to the MySqlDataAdapter constructor

Comment: When you receive the exception, can you look at the value of InnerException? Probably there is another clearer message there

Comment: Also according to the [MySql 9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) page, user and password are reserved keywords. In MySql you need to put them between backticks. Updating the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot frnd...It works very fine..Thank you...You taught me more...great job u did